# How to visually sort the order of Points with QGIS, GDAL, ...?

Tags: qgis, point, feature-layer, order, sorting

The following [Points layer](http://www.filedropper.com/muenster) is the basis of a rendering in a Android application.

[image: Points layer in QGIS]

Android allows to draw a shape from the provided **points**. I **cannot** use LineStrings.

[image: Points layer in Android]

However, the order of points exported from QGIS seems to be odd.

Is there any way to **visually sort** the order of points in QGIS or using the GDAL tools? The **order of feature ids** in the final export format (such as CSV) needs to be kind of a **roundtrip** as visualized in the following picture. If there are multiple paths or a "hole" it is perfectly okay to have multiple point layers.

[image: Points layer visualizing the roundtrip]

### Export experiments

I tried different steps to get hold of the latitude/longitude coordinates:

1. QGIS: Export points layer as CSV, add layer create options: `GEOMETRY=AS_YX`
2. Convert into Android specific format JSON format using regular expressions.

This has the disadvantage that the feature id is still included. The order of points however is **not** as desired.

1. `ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv input.shp -lco GEOMETRY=AS_YX`
2. Convert into Android specific format JSON format using regular expressions.

Here the feature id is already omitted. The order of points however is **not** as desired.

1. QGIS: Export points layer as GML
2. `ogr2ogr -f "CSV" -select "" output.csv input.gml -lco "GEOMETRY=AS_YX"`
3. Convert into Android specific format JSON format using regular expressions.

The order of points however is **not** as desired. The order of points is **different** to what the former exports/conversions output.

---

The original layer is also available as a [LineString layer](http://www.filedropper.com/muensterlinestrings).

Comment: How did you obtain points layer? What should be the result?

Comment: @zimmi The point layer is a export from OpenStreetMap and the result in Android should be a clean path (like a oval shape).

Comment: So you actually want to go through points one by another and connect them with a line. Is there any incrementing id associated with them that would help you tell what the previous and the next point should be?

Comment: @zimmi Please note that I uploaded the files - the link is at the beginning of the post. The ids are not unique. The original dataset is a LineStrings visualization of multiple parts. I would like to **avoid manually drawing** the path since I have to do the same for various layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in QGIS:

1. Load the polyline data from OSM
2. Reproject it to UTM 32N
3. `Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Buffer` with a value of 10 (metres) for `Buffer distance`.
4. `Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Dissolve` using `dissolve all` will lead to one polygon
5. `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Multipart to single part` creates one polygon for every LEZ with a hole in the middle
6. `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Polygons to Lines`
7. `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Lines to Polygons`
8. `Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Dissolve` using `dissolve all` will remove the inner ring
9. `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Multipart to single part` creates one polygon for every LEZ without hole
10. Using [Field Calculator](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html), create unique ids with a new field filled with $id
11. Install the MMQGIS plugin
12. `MMQGIS -> Import/Export -> Geometry Export` to CSV

For checking:

- Import as Delimited text layer
- Install [Points2One](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/points2one/) plugin
- Join the points to a line with Points2One

This works for Münster, but may fail on other cities (like Frankfurt, where a segment of the border is missing).

Comment: Can you please confirm I am doing the following steps correct? *Step 2:* I choose `Set Layer CRS` and select `WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N`. Can you explain why I have to reproject the layer? *Step 3:* When I process the layer this results in a egg-shaped thing for Muenster.

Comment: No, you have to `Rightclick -> Save As ...`.  Set CRS will not reproject the coordinates. OSM data is in degrees, and you don't want a 10 degrees buffer (That's your eggshape). Choosing a small degree value is also possible.

Comment: After *Step 9* the `Attributes Table` contains **one row**: `|4064462|Moltkestraße|`. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, could be. I did it with all type=LEZ relations. With only one LEZ, you can leave out step 9.

Comment: The `Attributes Table` contains **many rows** after *Step 3* and after *Step 4* **one** is remaining. Seems as if I am doing something wrong. - The polyline data in *Step 1* is retrieved [using OpenStreetMap Vector commands](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/79720/7690) as described in the beginning of your post, correct?

Comment: One (Multi-)Polygon in step 4 is correct, but is has a hole in the middle. With only one LEZ, you might skip step 5 also. The data is from Overpass API, correct.

Comment: Do you have time to talk about this in person (chat, skype)? I can not get the points sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Because the points for each `id` are already sorted, you can solve with:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT MakeLine(geometry), id FROM Muenster GROUP BY id" Muenster_lines.shp Muenster.shp
```

Then you can easily join the single lines and obtain the result path, as shown below:

[image]

**EDIT**

I think that it's not possible to sort all the points without defining a route based on a network topology. At the moment, you can only "order" the points with the same `id` calculating their `FID`, a special field of [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql.html). For instance:

```
ogr2ogr -where "id='5967589'" Muenster_5967589.shp Muenster.shp
ogr2ogr -f CSV -sql "SELECT FID FROM Muenster_5967589" -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY Muenster_5967589.csv Muenster_5967589.shp
```

This is the content of `Muenster_5967589.csv`:

```
X,Y,FID,
7.6175577,51.9619021,0
7.617543,51.9620712,1
7.617544,51.9623006,2
7.617577,51.9624964,3
7.6176213,51.9626584,4
7.6177773,51.9631274,5
7.617828,51.9634665,6
7.6178088,51.9638744,7
7.6177495,51.9647474,8
7.6176424,51.9652417,9
```

Comment: Agreed, the shape looks good in QGIS. But as [stated here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79752/how-to-convert-point-coordinates-into-csv-format) I need to export the **points (latitude, longitude) in the correct order** into a CSV file in order to process them in Android.

Comment: It seems that you have to solve a [Traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) before ordering all the points.

Answer (score 2):

The same result is achieved with the [Point2One](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/points2one/) plugin (and you can sort the points)

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: But key to the problem is that the order of **ids** does not necessarily match with the visual order I want to achieve for the roundtrip drawing I require for Android. I tried your approach but it still looks like a spiderweb in Android.

Comment: What is your visual order based on ?

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear, hopefully. I do not care about the starting point but I depend on the correct "roundtrip" order reflected by the order of coordinates in a export format such as CSV.

Comment: You need Graph Theory traversal algorithms or Networks algorithms (look at [Euclidean minimum spanning tree](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46657/how-to-interpolate-polyline-or-line-from-points/53467#53467), for example).

Comment: Appears definitely interesting. There is one fact I did not mention and excuse me for forgetting to mention this. The data is also available as `LineStrings`. Therefore, we **somehow know about the visual order**. "All I need" is to change the order of rows (id, lat, lon) for the Points export.

Comment: Try to extract the points from the LineString (order of the LineString)

Comment: The Line Strings are not ordered, and do not have the same orientation. If they can be connected (not as MutliLine) the point export is correct. That's the fun part of working with Openstreetmap data :-)