# Where does Open-Streetmap forest data come from?

Tags: openstreetmap, export

If you open this url

http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=50.6524658203125&mlon=9.4482421875&zoom=13

you are in a forest in germany. I downloaded the complete Open-Streetmap Data for Germany. I can find the waynodes for the tracks in this area... But not for the forest itself

Cna anyone help? Which way (id) defines the forest under the marker?

Or is it just the Background image for areas where's nothing defined?

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Relation:multipolygon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not find the forest in the ways list because it is build as a multipolygon relation:

http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/403306

Full text of the xml:

```
  <relation id='403306' timestamp='2012-01-17T23:33:35Z' uid='302852' user='be-ju' visible='true' version='26' changeset='10423448'>
    <member type='way' ref='132144354' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='145307496' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='145307467' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='132144347' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='132144358' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='30605404' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='31776954' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='34962555' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='45200953' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='45200956' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='47189443' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='49748068' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='49753651' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='52704700' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='52704705' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='52704706' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='55638793' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='55741659' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='55741754' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='55782868' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='59273778' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='60172815' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='60173689' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='60173735' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='70606150' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='70609895' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='72403561' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='72403567' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='90701038' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='90703459' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='90703461' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='90703467' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='90703470' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91066302' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91321239' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91321243' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91323839' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91323854' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91327023' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91327024' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91512913' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91512914' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91512915' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91512916' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91512918' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91512919' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91512920' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91512921' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91514545' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517126' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517128' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517130' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517132' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517133' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517135' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517137' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517140' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517918' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517921' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517931' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91517935' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91518210' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91518211' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91577434' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91577435' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91577436' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91577448' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91577453' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91577458' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91577484' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91577505' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91579362' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91579421' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91579429' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91579435' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91579437' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='93218137' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91072692' role='inner' />
    <member type='way' ref='91072698' role='inner' />
    <tag k='landuse' v='forest' />
    <tag k='note' v='c' />
    <tag k='type' v='multipolygon' />
  </relation>
```

If you have a local Postgis database filled with osm2pgsql you will find it in the planet_osm_polygon table with osm_id=-403306.

Most OSM importers still do not handle multipolygon relations correctly. If you need the way nodes, you have to download all ways that are part of the relation, then all nodes of those ways.

The members with role `outer` form one or several outer rings. You can not rely on the order in the file; the last node of the first member does not have to be the first node of the second. Same goes for the `inner` members.

As a consequence, you have to re-build the complete import logic of osm2pgsql. It is at least open source: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql

As a reference, you can take the OSM editor JOSM, and download a small part of the area of your interest.

Comment: Not planet_osm_poygon?

Comment: You are right, into planet_osm_line will go the **route** relations with negative ID.

Comment: Hi thanks.. ive imported the osm file by myself with a custom script... is there a sepcial xml-tag for these multipolygons?

Comment: You will find it at the end of the osm file: `<relation id='403306' timestamp='2012-01-17T23:33:35Z' uid='302852' user='be-ju' visible='true' version='26' changeset='10423448'>   ...   <tag k='type' v='multipolygon' />  ` . The landuse tags can be on the relation, or on the members with role=`outer`.

Comment: Noote that the multipolygon has 5 outer members, and these do not have to be stored in the logical order.

Comment: thank you very much! now my map wont have that much gaps

Comment: does "5 outer members" mean this wood has 5 not connected parts or will i have to connect these to get the full outer ring?

Comment: In this case, they form one outer ring. But you have to expect 5 isolated outers as well.

Comment: means i have to check if they are connected by my own?

Comment: this links was very helpful: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Relation:multipolygon

Comment: Yes, and some ways maybe in reversed direction.

Comment: hi could you have a look at this marker: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=50.32012939453125&mlon=8.8494873046875&zoom=13#map=15/50.3191/8.8535 is there something i could find the the database? Or is there nothing defined?

Comment: No, there is nothing except administrative boundaries around it. The slight grey you see is from the coastlines of Europe. These are not rendered from the database, but from polygon shapefiles to avoid leaks: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline

Comment: HI could you give me an example of an relation where "ways are in reversed direction"? Is there any algorithm to sort them?

Comment: This one could serve as an example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79778/how-to-visually-sort-the-order-of-points-with-qgis-gdal. osm2pgsql has an algorithm to solve it, but don't ask me where to find it...

Answer (score 1):

This should be a query in the land use layer.

Run this query.

landuse = forest

and this covers coniferous (pine forest) / deciduous (deciduous forest) / mixed (mixed forest)

This is the info

[http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Tag:landuse%3Dforest](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE%3aTag%3alanduse%3Dforest)

[http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:landuse](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3alanduse)

Comment: +1 for helpfull links which are hard to find when staring from wiki-homepage